# How to create a C++ object from Rust?

Tags: c++, rust, ffi

I know that a `Box<SomeRustStruct>` can be interpreted as a raw pointer `SomeRustStruct*` in C++, when the struct has a C representation.

How to do the converse? I only found some usages of bindgen.

How do I create and hold a pointer to a C++ object in Rust?

Answer (score 2):

The same way you [create and hold a pointer to a C object in Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/ffi.html#representing-opaque-structs): the C++ type would be represented by an opaque struct S on the Rust side, and the pointer is an `*mut S`.

You can also declare the type as a non-opaque type (but beware issues of layout in that case) if you need to perform direct field access on the Rust side but don't (want to) have accessor functions.

Comment: Could you explain how to return the new object in C++ to Rust? Some casting would be needed for the opaque types, right?